# WSo2 API Manager In Sequence to use Call Mediator to call a rest API which return empty JSON payload response but values in response headers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

we are using WSo2 API Manager 2.1.0.
when configuring an API in API Publisher we wanted to add a sequence of calls before calling the target API. So we added the In Sequence flow, where in a call Mediator we calling a REST API which return the values in response headers and a empty JSON Payload as 200.
In WSO2 API Manager we are getting the below response.

> <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
> <am:code>401001</am:code>
> <am:type>Status report</am:type>
> <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
> <am:description>Payload is not a JSON string.</am:description> </am:fault>

```
<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
        <property name="messageType" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="application/json"/> 
        <log level="full"/>
        <header name="site_id" scope="transport" value="004ada8a-6a11-f080-f56c-12dd3808e8f7"/>
        <header expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('generated-access-token'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
        <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
                <http method="put" uri-template="https://wso2.domainname.com/api/v1.0/users/me/login-defaults">
                    <suspendOnFailure>
                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                    </suspendOnFailure>
                    <markForSuspension>
                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    </markForSuspension>
                </http>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <log level="full"/>
        <property description="session-id" expression="$trp:X-NG-SessionId" name="session-id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$trp:X-NG-SessionId" name="Access Token after call if block"/>
        </log>
        <property expression="$ctx:resource" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```